# Getting Windows version with gcc c++

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, codeblocks

I'm sure this question is somewhat strange but I'm using Code::Blocks and GCC.
To use some specific functions in my project I need to determine which version of Windows is installed in the user machine.

With VS2013/15 we can use VersionHelpers.h and IsWindowsXXXOrGreater(). But what about GCC C++?

Comment: `#include Windows.h` and link with `Kernel32.lib` and `Ntdll.lib` as described in [documentationm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn424961(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still use `VersionHelpers.h`, even with GCC or Clang or another compiler. These functions have nothing to do with Visual C++. They are part of the Windows SDK, which all Windows applications have to use.

You can [download the Windows SDK from Microsoft](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) and install it on your development machine, if it is not already installed. Once installed, you'll need to tell Code::Blocks the path where it can find the SDK's header files and LIB files.

`VersionHelpers.h` will be among those headers (but all you need to include is `Windows.h`). The `VersionHelpers.h` file defines a series of inline functions which ultimately call down to functions exported from `kernel32.lib` and `ntdll.lib`. As long as the linker can find those LIB files, everything will work as expected.

Note, however, that it is rarely necessary to determine the actual version of Windows. Instead, you should be checking to see if the *features* you need are supported. If you want to call an API function that may not be available (for example, a function only supported on Windows 10, while you still need to support older versions), then you should [*dynamically* call that function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686944.aspx) by combining either `GetModuleHandle` or `LoadLibrary` with `GetProcAddress`. (If you call `LoadLibrary`, you must also call `FreeLibrary` when you are finished.)